# VS Code: Disable syntax highlighting for one line (or block)

Tags: babeljs, visual-studio-code

The syntax breaks when I use Optional Chaining or other TC39 stage 1 syntax.

**Is it possible to disable the syntax highlighter for one line?** Something similar to ES lint

`// eslint-disable-line`

Or **is it possible to manually change the syntax highlight rules to add optional chaining**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed with VS Code January release (1.20.0)
It still shows error/warning (red marker) where optional chaining is used, but the syntax highlighting is no longer broken.